# In ag-grid how do I make the active row color change to the selected row when the keyboard is used to navigate cells

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-vue

See below, when I used the keyboard arrow keys to move 1 row down, the highlighted row is still the one above it:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple!

Apply [setSelected](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-selection/#node-selection-api) method after finding the row your mouse focused using [onCellFocused](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-events/#reference-selection-cellFocused) event.

```
onCellFocused : function(params) {
  params.api.getRowNode(params.rowIndex).setSelected(true);
}
```

Here's the working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/L7dGwgp3xYWunOFH